# Select Input for an asset in Liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet

How to use liferay-ui:input-asset-links tag to get an input of the selected asset and how to filter out the asset type to be selected i.e. to show only images from the menu.

Thanks,
Aanand

Comment: Can you elaborate more what exactly you are looking for ?

Comment: need a input from the users where they can choose an existing image from Documents and Media.

Comment: I would suggest you to go through journal jsps. In web content creation form there is related assets where you select Document & Media display which list all documents in popup. Which is coming from journal/select_document_library you can go through this follow and build your logic accordingly.